# the connection property has not been initialized

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, interface

I'm trying to run this code for my user interfaces, I connected the interface with my database and I did everything correctly. But the problem is this error keeps showing and I have no clue in how to fix it.

The error says "the connection property has not been initialized"

And this is my code,

```
Public Class ManageBus
Private Sub btnclear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles      btnclear.Click
    txtbus.Text = Nothing
    txtdriver = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub btnexit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnexit.Click
    End
End Sub

Private Sub btnadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click
    Try

        OracleConnection1.Open()
        Dim command As String
        command = "insert into BUS(Bus_ID, Driver_ID)" _
                  & " values('" & txtbus.Text & "', '" _
                  & txtdriver.Text & ")"

        OracleDataAdapter1.InsertCommand.CommandText = command

        lblsql.Text = command

        OracleDataAdapter1.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Insert Successful", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Insert      Status")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        OracleConnection1.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: I tried to add OracleDataAdapter1.Connection = OracleConnection1 but it gives me that connection is not a member of OracleDataAdapter1

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the connectionstring for the connection to setup the connection. For example:

```
Dim OracleConnection1 As New OracleConnection("Data Source=ORCL;User Id=test;Password=test;");
OracleConnection1.Open();
```

Comment: I tried and it says that type OracleConnection is not defined, even though I added the item OracleConnection after I connected my database with the interface.